# ImageView not detecting clicks when used with ViewPager

Tags: android, onclick, android-viewpager, android-imageview

I have the following XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/welcome_bg" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrowLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/arrow_left"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrowRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/arrow_right"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_right" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/tutorialViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is that when the user clicks on the left arrow or the right arrow then the pager should flip, but i am not able to get click events on the leftarrow or the rightarrow ImageView. I am not able to get the event when the arrows are clicked. I have set onClickListeners on both the arrows but they are never called. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to use `rightArrow.bringToFront()` and `leftArrow.bringToFront()`. That brought the buttons to front and i was able to get a click event on them.

Comment: Generally, you need to be careful with FrameLayout, as its child views can easily end up on top of each other. Which is what happened here. You can use the android:layout_gravity attribute to control how the children are laid out inside the FrameLayout.

Comment: @ohra In this case the children were not on each other. They were placed properly. the only problem problem was that they went behind the viewpager. I was already using the android:layout_gravity attribute in my code.

Comment: @Antrromet, actually the bringToFront() is not the best solution. I"m having the same problem and while bringToFront() temporariliy fixes it by bringing the button to the front and enabling on click event, it fixes the arrows on the page, so it looks like there are arrows on the top and when swiping, there are arrows in the back too. Do you want to discuss further in chat? I will post a question regarding my problem. Thanks!